# Windows 7 - How to gain full admin rights when already part of administrators group?

Tags: windows-7, uac, admin

I have a Windows 7 development machine and I am constantly encountering the "you do not have enough permissions" when running certain programs or trying to access log files. I am the only user on the machine and my account is part of the administrators group. Is this part of Microsoft's UAC "protection"? If so, is there a way to remove it so that an administrator account has full admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you can right click and select "Run as Administrator" to elevate the privilege. I believe, You can also turn it off from control panel (search for "User access control" in control panel). I would not recommend it though. If you have applications to start up with that privilege, you might want to modify the shortcut to have "Run as Administrator" set so that it will challenge you as soon as it starts.